# $.inArray only checks the last index of array in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
var items=[];
 $.get('./list.txt', {
    now: $.now()
}, function(data) {
 items = data.split('\n');
 
 });
  $('#input1').keyup(function(e){
  var first = $('#input1').val();
    if($.inArray(first.replace(/\s/g, ''),items) > -1){
    $('#showHide').show();
   }
    )};
```

I am actually trying to type in the first input field and after typing 6 numbers then 4th input which is hidden by default in showen after 6 digit number if the number is present in the text file which i loaded from my local server.The text file has different 6 digits numbers which are separated by '\n'. I have list of different numbers in my text file, but when i type the 6 digit number in the input field which is the last 6 digit number in the text file, only that matches and 4th input which is hidden by default is showen and others are not working when i type that 6 digit numbers. What i am doing wrong?

thank in advance.

Answer (score 2):

So by re-organizing your code I was able to find that you have swapped the right parenthesis and the right curly brace at the end of your code. Here is a cleaned up and fixed (hopefully) version of your code.

```js
var items=[];
$.get('./list.txt', {now: $.now()}, function(data) {
items = data.split('\n');
 
});
$('#input1').keyup(function(e){
    var first = $('#input1').val();
    if($.inArray(first.replace(/\s/g, ''),items) > -1){
  $('#showHide').show();
 }
}); // <--- HERE
```

Comment: sorry bro, this is not an issue. I apologize for it but i typed the parenthesis mistakenly here. the error is not due to this issue.